# PHP5-GD in Debian Testing missing Dependency libvpx1

Tags: php, debian, apt, php-gd

I run Debian Testing on my dev Server. Unfortunatley I have to work with mysqli (which is not included in php7) and php-gd at the same time.

cat /etc/issue

```
Debian GNU/Linux stretch/sid
```

apt-get install php5-gd

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-gd : Depends: libvpx1 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

more sources.list

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
```

Somewhere I found the information, that the needed libvpx1 is not included in testing anymore. But I still need it. Seems that I will have to install it manually somehow. Which way would you recommend?

Btw apt-get install -f and such does not solve the problem, since libvpx1 is not included in testing at all. https://packages.debian.org/sid/libvpx1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK this one was pretty easy:

```
wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libv/libvpx/libvpx1_1.3.0-3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libvpx1_1.3.0-3_amd64.deb
apt-get install php5-gd
```

Worked.

Comment: You just saved my night :)

Comment: That's why I always post my own answers :)